# How to test conditional redirection in controller method with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rspec, controller

I have that method in my controller

```
  def promotional_sales
    redirect_to plans_path and return unless promotional_campaign_active?
    config_meta_tags({}, {
      title: "Subscription promotion in our website",
      description: "Do you want to know more about our website promotions? Stay on top of all promotions and guarantee your discount"
    })
    if control_flag[:phase] == "captation"
      setup_promotional_campaign
      render :promotion_3
    end
    if control_flag[:phase] == "sales"
      setup_courage_hotsite
      render :hotsite_1
    end
  end
end
```

I would like do write a RSpec test that cover if the redirection to `plans_path` is happening when promotional campaign is inactive and if is active goes to the next block.

Please, can you guide me how do I write this test?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [redirect_to](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/redirect-to-matcher) matcher. Based on your condition you can expect response to be redirected or not

when promotional campaign is inactive

```
expect(response).to redirect_to(plans_path)
```